# Unable to connect to wildfly server in eclipse

Tags: wildfly

Errors in console log

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\wildfly-12.0.0.Final\standalone\log\server.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)
> at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:151)
> at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.setFile(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:108)
> at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java:189)
> at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.(FileHandler.java:119)
> at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:76)
> ... 22 more
> WFLYSRV0073: Invalid option '=C:/Software'

[image]